# Problem with charset on SQL*PLUS

Tags: oracle

We are creating scripts to sent to our customers, with some inserts. We save them with ANSI encoding on NOTEPAD++, but when the customer runs the script via SQL*PLUS, it looks like this:

[image]

How can I be sure that the customer will run the script, with ansi encode, so we have no problems with those symbols on â, ó and et.

We told them to customize their environment to use NSL_LANG = WE8MSWIN1252.
TEST QUERY:

```
Select *,
Case
        When Teste_CHAR=Teste_CHAR_ASCII
        Then 'OK'
        Else 'Erro'
END as STATUS_TESTE,
Case
       When Teste_CHAR=Teste_CHAR_ASCII
       Then 'Everything is OK'
       Else 'Script will not run. your encode is different from ours'
END as Mensagem_TESTE
 from (
Select CHAR(ASCII('ã')) As Teste_CHAR, CHAR(227) as Teste_CHAR_ASCII
) A
```

as said here ( **[How to be sure that a SQL Script is running with ANSI encoding?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/190445/how-to-be-sure-that-a-sql-script-is-running-with-ansi-encoding) ) **this is not correct. But, is there a way to use something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First problem is: What do you mean by **ANSI**?

`ANSI` is a common misnomer for your default Windows character set. It depends on your Windows language. See a list of codepages on [National Language Support (NLS) API Reference](https://web.archive.org/web/20171015144140/https://www.microsoft.com/resources/msdn/goglobal/default.mspx) (column "ANSI codepage")

You can also query your Registry to get it:

```
C:\>reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage /v ACP

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage
    ACP    REG_SZ    1252
```

Let's assume it is `CP1252`, the most common on "Western" PC's

When you run SQL*Plus then it inherits the codepage from your `cme.exe`. However this is not "ANSI codepage", you get it in column "OEM codepage" or by Registry

```
C:\>reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage /v OEMCP

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage
    OEMCP    REG_SZ    850
```

This is typically `CP850` (for Western Europe) or `CP437` (in US)

You can change and interrogate the code page by command `chcp`

`NLS_LANG` parameter tells the database which character set you are using (because the Oracle Database cannot interrogate your settings from Notepad++ or `cmd.exe`)

So, it order to make it working run following:

```
C:\>chcp 1252
Active code page: 1252

C:\>set NLS_LANG=.WE8MSWIN1252

C:\>sqlplus user/pwd@DB @xyz.sql
```

Comment: Thank you very much, BUt just one question that I can't find the answer on google. Why oracle uses OEMCP ? I could run ACP on my machine, and I got 1252. but running OEMCP, I got 850. I didn't understand what this means. by the way I'm from Brazil.

Comment: Sorry...Why SQL*PLUS use OEMCP codepage?

Comment: SQL*Plus inherits the code page (or name it "character set" if you prefer the term) from calling command-line (this also applies for Linux/Unix). The problem is Microsoft Windows which by default uses on command-line (i.e. `cmd.exe`) a different code page than on GUI applications (where it is typically called just "ANSI"). I found this blog: http://archives.miloush.net/michkap/archive/2005/02/08/369197.html regarding this topic.

Comment: In earlier times there was an application `sqlplusw.exe` GUI based, i.e. that one used ACP. But it does not exist anymore in current Oracle releases.

Comment: Is there a way to TEST the script, BEFORE running it? Lets say, some kind of comparison between `maçã` and the codepage on the target system? and if the target finds and error  ( Lets say, we test it with `ãóô`, and if the target server can't find these characters, it gives an error and we just stop the script ).  is there a way to test this in a script? I posted an idea on the question. I don't think it will work. By the way, using `chcp` worked.

Comment: Yes, write a PL/SQL block like `begin
IF UNISTR('\20AC') = '€' THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( '"€" is equal to U+20AC' ); ELSE DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( '"€" is not the same as U+20AC' ); END IF;
end;
/
` Euro currency symbol `€` is Unicode character [U+20AC](https://codepoints.net/U+20AC)

Comment: Thank you . I will translate this to SQL server too. if I'm not mistaken, it would work there too, right? Thank you for your patience. This is a really confused topic for me to explain.

Comment: Yes, should be the same